Segmentation Fault in unexpected location when I add a for loop to main
I wrote the code below, in a C file called Practice_3.c to practice my C which I am quite rusty at. There are standard inputs at the top, a few function declarations/definitions and a few structs. Now, if you notice the very bottom of the code, I have a for loop that basically does nothing relevant (or at least I thought so). However, with this for-loop here this is my output.
type herHello, World
 b is now: 5

The 0th element of the array is: 0.
The 1th element of the array is: 1.
The 2th element of the array is: 2.
The 3th element of the array is: 3.
The 4th element of the array is: 4.
The 5th element of the array is: 5.
The 6th element of the array is: 6.
The 7th element of the array is: 7.
The 8th element of the array is: 8.
The 9th element of the array is: 9.
3
Value is: 13

Value is: 100
zsh: segmentation fault  ./Practice_3e

Now, if I remove the for-loop and just leave the print statement, the program runs normally But with this for-loop at the bottom (and I have even tried commenting out the print statement inside) I get this segmentation fault. What further confuses me, is if you look to see where the segmentation fault is, it occurs after the print statements "Value is:..." Now, when I remove the for-loop at the bottom, the output becomes the following:
tHello, World
 b is now: 5

The 0th element of the array is: 0.
The 1th element of the array is: 1.
The 2th element of the array is: 2.
The 3th element of the array is: 3.
The 4th element of the array is: 4.
The 5th element of the array is: 5.
The 6th element of the array is: 6.
The 7th element of the array is: 7.
The 8th element of the array is: 8.
The 9th element of the array is: 9.
3
Value is: 13

d

0
The y coordinate of point1 is: -1
The coordinates for point4 are 7 and 12
For this one our coordinates are 10
The bottom left of our rectangle is 38
Arr of 0 is: -4.

The 0th element of arrAgain is: -8
The 1th element of arrAgain is: -3
The 2th element of arrAgain is: 0
The 3th element of arrAgain is: 4
The 4th element of arrAgain is: 7
The 5th element of arrAgain is: 11
The 6th element of arrAgain is: 12
The 7th element of ype here

Note that 1) given my code below in the part where I print the "value is:..." the correct working of the code only prints "Value is: 13" and does not print "Value is: 100" afterwards as the conditions to continue within that loop are not met. 2) This region of code is NOT close to the lines of code which cause this issue which are THE FOR LOOP AT THE BOTTOM. It isn't one of the other for loops causing this, it is just that for loop. That said, if I copy/paste that loop somewhere else within main the error persists, but if I remove the loop and put in a different statement (say a print statement) there is no segmentation fault.
I cannot figure out why an isolated for-loop in main has the effect of causing a seg-fault and causing the set-fault in an earlier and unrelated section of main. Why does adding a loop with "junk" / "hello world" type content cause the "Value is:..." / node struct to give me a seg fault.
This is so strange. I have restarted VS-Code, I have checked my compiler (gcc) but as long as there is a for-loop in main this issue arises. My irrational mind is almost wondering if I reached the upper-bound for the number of for-loops allowed in main which is then causing this error. I am beyond confused why this would be the case, the interactions between these areas of code and...well, everything about this.
Here is the code. It is only this file, there are no linked files or header files or anything. If anyone has any idea please let me know.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

struct node {
    int val;
    struct node* left;
    struct node* right;
};

void swap(int* x, int* y){
    int temp = *y;
    *y = *x;
    *x = temp;
}

int modular(int base, int val){
    if(val < 0){
        return modular(base, -val);
    }
    else if(val < base){
        return val;
    }
    else {
        return modular(base, val-base);
    }
}

struct point {
    int x;
    int y;
} point1, point2; 

struct point makePoint(int x, int y){
    struct point temp;
    temp.x = x;
    temp.y=y;
    return temp; 
}

struct rect {
    struct point pt1;
    struct point pt2;
} myRect; 

void insertionSort(int* head, int arrLength){
    for(int i = 0; i < arrLength; i++){
        for(int j = i+1; j < arrLength; j++){
            //printf("Here we have %d\n", *(head+j));
            if(*(head + j) < *(head + i)){
                int temp = *(head + j);
                *(head + j) = *(head + i);
                *(head + i) = temp;
            }
        }
        //printf("We've reached here...");   
    }
    return;
}

int main(){
    printf("Hello, World");
    int a = 5;
    int b = 3;
    swap(&a, &b);
    printf("\n b is now: %d\n", b);

    int arr[10];
    int l = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
    for(int i = 0; i < l; i++) {
        arr[i] = i;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < l; i++){
        printf("\nThe %dth element of the array is: %d.", i, *(arr+i));
    }
    //printf("The 2nd element in the array is: %d", (*arr+1));

    int i1 = 3;
    int* px = &i1;
    printf("\n%d", *px);

    struct node root; 
    root.val = 13;
    struct node left1;
    struct node left2;
    left1.val = 100;
    left2.val = 2;
    root.left = &left1;
    root.right = &left2;

    struct node curr = root;
    while(curr.left != NULL){
        printf("\nValue is: %d\n", curr.val);
        curr = *curr.left;
    }

    char s[] = "Hi, my name is Aaron";
    printf("\n%c\n", s[16]+3);

    int one = modular(8, 104);
    printf("\n%d\n", one);

    point1.x = 1;
    point1.y = -1;
    printf("The y coordinate of point1 is: %d\n", point1.y);

    struct point point3;
    struct point point4 = {7, 12};
    printf("The coordinates for point4 are %d and %d\n", point4.x, point4.y);

    struct point aP = makePoint(10, 10);
    printf("For this one our coordinates are %d\n", aP.x);

    myRect.pt1 = makePoint(38, 38);
    printf("The bottom left of our rectangle is %d\n", myRect.pt1);

    int arr8[10];
    arr8[0] = -4;
    printf("Arr of %d is: %d.\n\n", 0, arr8[0]);


    int arrAgain[] = {7, 4, -3, 0, -8, 11, 31, 12};
    insertionSort(arrAgain, sizeof(arrAgain)/sizeof(arrAgain[0]));
    for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(arrAgain)/sizeof(arrAgain[0]); i++){
        printf("The %dth element of arrAgain is: %d\n", i, arrAgain[i]);
    }

    int* pointer1;
    printf("Size here is: %d\n", sizeof(pointer1));

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        printf("x");
    }

}

I tried replacing the for-loop with other "Hello-World" (i.e. 'irrelevant') type expressions - which caused a change I was NOT expecting. I moved the loop around within main - which kept the seg-fault still. I tried restarting VSCode, I tried commenting out the for-loop (which had an effect). I would expect that the code would work the same with or without those 3 lines at the end, and if it does perform differently, why the difference appears in a section of the code multiple lines above this point.

while(curr.left != NULL){         . . .          curr = *curr.left; left1.left was never initialized. This will attempt to use it. Potential seg fault right there. Haven't gotten to your for loop.

Wow, that fixed it!! I feel so stupid and at the same time never would have thought of that. Thank you so much!!!

C11 Standard - 7.21.6.1 The fprintf function(p2) "If there are insufficient arguments for the format, the behavior is undefined."[7.21.6.1(p9)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.1p9)"If a conversion specification is invalid, the behavior is undefined. If any argument is not the correct type for the corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is undefined." %dis not the proper specifier for a pointer."%p"is with a cast to(void*). Avoid int<unsigned` comparisons.

Did your compiler not warn you that printf("The bottom left of our rectangle is %d\n", myRect.pt1); attempts to pass a structure for %d? Enable warnings in your compiler and elevate warnings to errors.  With Clang, start with -Wmost -Werror. With GCC, start with -Wall -Werror. With MSVC, start with /W3 /WX.

because the left and left children of your new left1 and left2 structs are not initialized, there is a problem with the pointing of the two structs, there is a wild pointer situation, so there is a segment error
struct node left1;
struct node left2;
left1.val = 100;
//add
left1.left=NULL;
left1.right=NULL;
left2.val = 2;
//add
left2.left=NULL;
left2.right=NULL;
root.left = &left1;
root.right = &left2;


you can also wirte a  struct initialization function  to initlize each of these structs


Note that 1) given my code below in the part where I print the "value is:..." the correct working of the code only prints "Value is: 13" and does not print "Value is: 100" afterwards as the conditions to continue within that loop are not met. 2) This region of code is NOT close to the lines of code which cause this issue which are THE FOR LOOP AT THE BOTTOM.

Your problem is one of initialization as @AviBerger notes in his first comment, but you need to understand why. When you declare your structs (which have automatic storage duration), the values of each of the struct members are indeterminate. C doesn't automatically zero values for you when variables are created with automatic storage duration -- that is up to you. Until the members are initialized or set, you cannot access the values.
Your problem arises here:
    struct node root; 
    root.val = 13;
    struct node left1;
    struct node left2;
    left1.val = 100;
    left2.val = 2;
    root.left = &left1;
    root.right = &left2;

Here you declare structs root, left1 and left2. You assign values to the val member of each and assign addresses to root.left and root.right. However, you NEVER assign values to the pointer member of left1 or left2 (e.g. their .left and .right members). Now when you attempt to iterate with:
    struct node curr = root;
    while(curr.left != NULL){
        printf("\nValue is: %d\n", curr.val);
        curr = *curr.left;
    }

... The value of the left1.left pointer is indeterminate. You Invoke Undefined Behavior by attempting to access its value. The number in left1.left can be anything and is very likely outside the valid range of memory addresses available to your program. Attempting to access a memory address outside valid program memory leads to you SegFault.

C11 Standard - 6.7.9 Initialization(p10) "If an object that has automatic storage duration is not initialized explicitly, its value is indeterminate."

You can save yourself a lot of grief by simply initializing all of your structs and arrays as you are learning C. That will prevent this type of Undefined Behavior. When initializing a struct you can either provide initialization for each member or simply initialize, in order from the beginning, those that need initialization, and in that case, any not initialized will be initialized zero, e.g.

§ 6.7.9 Initialization (p19)
The initialization shall occur in initializer list order, each initializer provided for a particular subobject overriding any previously listed initializer for the same subobject151 all subobjects that are not initialized explicitly shall be initialized implicitly the same as objects that have static storage duration.

In your case you can fully initialize your structs for that iteration using a named-initializer (c99+) as:
  struct node left1 = {.val = 100 };
  struct node left2 = {.val = 2 };
  struct node root = {.val = 13, .left = &left1, .right = &left2 };

Now with the undefined behavior eliminated, your code will execute with both loops as you intend.
Since you say you are using gcc, then use it correctly and enable Full Warnings. Always compile with warnings enabled, and do not accept code until it compiles without warning. To enable warnings add -Wall -Wextra -pedantic to your gcc/clang compile string (also consider adding -Wshadow to warn on shadowed variables and -Werror to treat warnings as errors). Optimization levels -O0 through -O3 (and post gcc-4.6 -Ofast) are provided with increasingly aggressive compiler optimization of your code. (default is -O2 shown). To have gcc output debug symbols in the executable for use with gdb add -g.
A sample compile string for your code saved in modular.c would be:
gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Wshadow -Werror -std=c11 -O2 -o modular modular.c

After compiling, your code gives the results you desire (with the order and a few formatting changes to clean it up a bit).
Don't include "\n" at the beginning of your printf() format-strings (unless unavoidable). Instead, if you know you want to leave a space, include "...\n\n" at the end of your previous output. You should not have to remember "Do I add a '\n' at the start?" every time you write to stdout. Get in the habit of each output standing on its own. When you call a function defined 1000 lines away, you don't want to have to scroll to see if it has a beginning '\n' or not...
That said, your program output is now:
$ ./modular
Hello, World
b is now: 5

The 0th element of the array is: 0
The 1th element of the array is: 1
The 2th element of the array is: 2
The 3th element of the array is: 3
The 4th element of the array is: 4
The 5th element of the array is: 5
The 6th element of the array is: 6
The 7th element of the array is: 7
The 8th element of the array is: 8
The 9th element of the array is: 9
*px = 3

Value is: 13
Value is: 100

d
one = 0

The y coordinate of point1 is: -1
The coordinates for point4 are (7,12)
For this one our coordinates are 10
The bottom left of our rectangle is (38,38)
Arr of 0 is: -4.

The 0th element of arrAgain is: -8
The 1th element of arrAgain is: -3
The 2th element of arrAgain is: 0
The 3th element of arrAgain is: 4
The 4th element of arrAgain is: 7
The 5th element of arrAgain is: 11
The 6th element of arrAgain is: 12
The 7th element of arrAgain is: 31

Size here is: 8
xxxxx

Also note to be POSIX compliant, you program must output a final '\n' (to keep from screwing up the command-line prompt). Your "xxxxx" output fails to do that. Simply add a putchar('\n'); at the end. (yes, you output single-characters with putchar(), not a string function that has to scan for the end of string).
Your cleaned up code -- with additional help provided as comments in the code is as follows:
#include <stdio.h>
// #include <stdlib.h>    /* don't include unused headers */
// #include <math.h>

struct node {
  int val;
  struct node *left;
  struct node *right;
};

void swap (int *x, int *y)
{
  int temp = *y;
  *y = *x;
  *x = temp;
}

int modular (int base, int val)
{
  if (val < 0) {
    return modular (base, -val);
  }
  else if (val < base) {
    return val;
  }
  /* useless else {, only 1 thing can happen at that point */
  return modular (base, val - base);
}

struct point {
  int x;
  int y;
} point1, point2;

struct point makePoint (int x, int y)
{
  struct point temp;
  temp.x = x;
  temp.y = y;
  return temp;
}

struct rect {
  struct point pt1;
  struct point pt2;
} myRect;

void insertionSort (int *head, int arrLength)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < arrLength; i++) {
    for (int j = i + 1; j < arrLength; j++) {
      if (*(head + j) < *(head + i)) {
        swap (head + i, head + j);        /* you have a swap function */
      }
    }
  }
}

int main ()
{
  puts ("Hello, World");
  int a = 5;
  int b = 3;
  swap (&a, &b);
  printf ("b is now: %d\n\n", b);

  int arr[10] = {0};
  int l = sizeof (arr) / sizeof (arr[0]);   /* should use size_t not int */
  for (int i = 0; i < l; i++) {             /* which would change here too */
    arr[i] = i;
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < l; i++) {     /* and change here ..., and %zu for i */
    printf ("The %dth element of the array is: %d\n", i, *(arr + i));
  }

  int i1 = 3;
  int *px = &i1;
  printf ("*px = %d\n\n", *px);

  struct node left1 = {.val = 100 };
  struct node left2 = {.val = 2 };
  struct node root = {.val = 13, .left = &left1, .right = &left2 };

  struct node curr = root;
  while (1) {
    printf ("Value is: %d\n", curr.val);
    if (curr.left == NULL) {        /* your loop must break here */
      break;
    }
    curr = *curr.left;
  }
  
  char s[] = "Hi, my name is Aaron";
  if (s[16] + 3 <= '~') {           /* validate the result is ASCII */
    printf ("\n%c\n", s[16] + 3);
  }
  else {
    fputs ("requested character (s[16] + 3) exceeds ASCII range.\n", stderr);
  }

  int one = modular (8, 104);
  printf ("one = %d\n\n", one);

  point1.x = 1;
  point1.y = -1;
  printf ("The y coordinate of point1 is: %d\n", point1.y);

  // struct point point3;         /* don't include unused variables */
  struct point point4 = { 7, 12 };
  printf ("The coordinates for point4 are (%d,%d)\n", point4.x, point4.y);

  struct point aP = makePoint (10, 10);
  printf ("For this one our coordinates are %d\n", aP.x);

  myRect.pt1 = makePoint (38, 38);
  printf ("The bottom left of our rectangle is (%d,%d)\n",
          myRect.pt1.x, myRect.pt1.y);

  int arr8[10] = {0};     /* initialize ALL arrays */
  arr8[0] = -4;
  printf ("Arr of %d is: %d.\n\n", 0, arr8[0]);


  int arrAgain[] = { 7, 4, -3, 0, -8, 11, 31, 12 };
  size_t nelem = sizeof arrAgain / sizeof *arrAgain;
  
  insertionSort (arrAgain, nelem);
  for (size_t i = 0; i < nelem; i++) {
    printf ("The %zuth element of arrAgain is: %d\n", i, arrAgain[i]);
  }

  int *pointer1;
  printf ("\nSize here is: %zu\n", sizeof pointer1);

  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    putchar ('x');                /* you putchar() a single character */
  }

  putchar ('\n');                 /* your program must end with a \n */
}

Let me know if you have further questions.

Re “Unless and until you initialize the struct or assign values to each member, the values are just whatever happens to be located in memory at that point”: This is not specified by the C standard and does not always occur. Teaching students this incorrect statement may cause incorrect diagnosis of bugs.

Re “you Invoke Undefined Behavior by attempting to access the values of (i.e., the address held by) the pointer members of your left1.left pointer”: This does not cause undefined behavior in OP’s code. Annex J is only a summary to help people identify issues and find the authoritative text in the standard. It is marked informative and not normative, so it is not an authoritative part of the standard. The actual rule is in C 2018 6.3.2.1 2, and it does not apply because left1 could not have been declared register, since its address is taken.

@EricPostpischil - he specified gcc. How would you word the indeterminate state of the struct members then? They are declared with automatic storage duration and they are accessed while their value is indeterminate. What magic words are you looking for?

You do not need to add new wording or “magic words” so much as take out the wrong words. Just say the structure values are indeterminate, and the program needs to set their values. Take out the incorrect references to undefined behavior and that “the values are just whatever happens to be located in memory at that point.”

That makes more sense. Thank you.
